# how to get postgres to do parallel inserts with cte query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a CTE query returning 750m records, these records need to be inserted into a target table. Using "select * into <> from " clause to parallelize the query part, but is there a way to parallelize the insert part? PostgreSQL version is 11.6.

Would having target table as partitioned help in parallelizing the insert? If so then how to run a CTAS for a partitioned table - lets say hash partitioned table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to parallelize INSERTs in PostgreSQL, except by opening several database connections and using them in parallel.

Comment: But the fact that there is only one transaction log file is a bootleneck that cannot process anyway with paralelization because TLF are WAL file (Write Ahead Log) that induce sequential writes before achieving INSERT. Only RDBMS that are able to use "In Memory" table can have real parallelized INSERTs...

Comment: Oracle was able to use parallel DML long before they had "in memory" tables. Also WAL supports parallel inserts (and updates and deletes) from multiple transactions on the same table, so that is not a limitation for parallel DML from a single statement.

Comment: There is so much limitations to Oracle paralle DML (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-6626C70C-876C-47A4-8C01-9B66574062D8.htm#GUID-6626C70C-876C-47A4-8C01-9B66574062D8) which works only for partitionned tables, that only very few queries can be able to take advantage of that... And also the transaction log is always write in serial mode... Of course MS SQL Server do the same since 2008 version !

Comment: "*which works only for partitionned tables*" is flat out wrong. But we all know that you are paid by Microsoft to praise sQl SerVer and bad-mouth PostgreSQL any time you have the chance to.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19868/sql-server-parallelism-for-dml-operations) sQl serVer started to support parallel DML only since 2014. And [this](https://houri33.rssing.com/chan-11166181/article147.html) claims you need 2016

Comment: SQL Server can use DPV since version 2000. This is a parallelized federation of database with a transaction log file for each db / instance https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/distributed-partitioned-views-federated-databases-lessons/ba-p/304955

Answer (score 0):

I tried 23 millions rows copy by "insert into/select from" clause in one shot and it took: **25m 3s**

When I split those records into 10 different tables each have 2.3 millions rows and started 10 different "insert into/select from" query  in 10 different sessions (different DataGrip tabs) it took: **11m 33s**

I found this answer which claims different from what I experienced.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301426/parallelize-select-insert-for-postgresql

Answer (score -3):

Totally agree that MSSQL and Postgres features are far behind Oracle ones. My advice is to start using them in some real world tasks and then the issues will become obvious. My list is endless..
Inner SQL parallelism..
Partitioning..
Autnomous transactions..
Locking..

In MSSQL server readers block writers and oposite since it is born .. don't believe their snapshot isolation level will help as it is at transaction level...

In short.. be profesionals and do your homework well :)

Comment: Agree, "what you pay is what you get"

Comment: btw, MSSQL has introduced the "optimistic locking" model at statement level, but it is an option of their READ_COMMITED isolation level. It is so misleading by them, but at least it is there... So, I was wrong they don't have it.. It is just well hidden and is not the default.

Comment: @Edward-Hayrabedian You are wrong about "their snapshot isolation level [...] it is at transaction level". Optimistic locking can be a transaction level if you set the database to use a mix of optimistic and pessimistic locking (setting the db to "ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION") or a database can be in optimistic locking exclusive mode if the db setting is "READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT". Then in this last mode it is the strict equivalent to Oracle or PostGreSQL which is the the only behaviour they accepts...

Comment: Yes, finally it is there.. Hopefully, the rest of the missing features will be added too :)